# Sending http request to local server using appcelerator

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am developing mobile apps with appcelerator. My problem is, I am not able to calling REST web service using Android emulator i.e server is in my local system

I am getting "not found" error message, also I am using my local IPV4 Address in emulator, but no luck.

Comment: stackoverflow will not write code for you. Specify what you need. What error you get etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to access your REST services from your local server from your emulator.

So if you are using your REST services using localhost then try as follow.

If your webservice URL as below,

http://www.example.com/YOUR_WEB_SERVICE_NAME

Then replace [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with 10.0.2.2 because you are running your application from emulator, so you will have to use your localserver using 10.0.2.2.

Comment: actually, i set up the port number is 3000 and i called up my service in the following way: 10.0.2.2:3000/issues.json. It is working in phonegap android emulator. But not working in titanium based emulator.

Comment: Have you tried with 10.0.2.2:80/issues.json or 10.0.2.2:8080/issues.json, that might be work with titanium.

Comment: I tried with first option, but again same problem i.e not found. Also i tried with second option but no response.